# uiwebview detect youtube video is loaded completeley

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiwebview, youtube

I am playing youtube video in uiwebview using following code

```
                NSString *embedHTML = @"\
                <html><head>\
                <style type=\"text/css\">\
                body {\
                background-color: transparent;\
                color: white;\
                }\
                </style>\
                </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
                width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
                </body></html>";
                NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, videoToken, videoView.frame.size.width, videoView.frame.size.height];


                [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

My problem is that until the youtube video is not loaded I want to show loading or some thing to say it is being loaded. I tried to detect in webview did finish load, but it comes 2-3 times in that method.

Please help

Answer (score -1):

If you want to detect video is loaded or not then use below method , it is delegate method of UIWebview

You must set delegate of UIWebview in your View Controller Class.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   //your code here
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but in webViewDidFinishLoad it comes more then once, and when I try to get request url from webview it always gives me about:blank